# Will changing my minecraft name mean losing friends?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If I were to change my Minecraft account name, would I lose friends or not?

Answer (score 4):

No.

Changing your name does nothing more than change the label of the account. You still own the account, you still maintain the same progress, you still maintain the same list of friends. Logging on might be a hitch (once; due to the account name change), but that's it.

The *only* way this might affect your friends is if they aren't aware of the account name-change, they may not realise it's still you, and remove you. If you're really worried about losing friends, then warn them of the name change beforehand.

Comment: Though, if you change your name to "IHateBob", then you could lose Bob as a friend.

Comment: @Khale_Kitha sound advice